# Is there a number limit for region based notifications?

Tags: ios

As per apple's doc regarding to core location:

> Core Location limits to 20 the number of regions that may be
>   simultaneously monitored by a single app.

But with region based local notification apple says:

> An app can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the
>   system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically
>   rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and
>   discards the rest.

So my question is there a limited number for region based notifications on iOS? In my understanding, it should be 64. But will the system automatically reschedule the most nearest 64 region based notifications?

Thanks.